# Figuring out what caused a system hang

Tags: linux-mint, logs, skype, forensics, hang

Over the past several hours I've had my Mint 18.2 system hang on me - twice during a Skype (64-bit) conversation, and a third time. Screen locks up, audio repeats a short pattern, no response to keyboard or mouse. After a reboot, everything seems to work again. Such a hang has not happened to me before on this system.

I've tried looking here-and-there in `/var/log`, but I can't seem to find traces of the "impending doom". Where/how can I look for more clues regarding what happened?

Notes: I'm not interested in approaches like removing pieces of hardware and seeing when this behavior stops; that's a valid approach, but I'm hoping for some after-the-fact evidence to suggest what had happened.

Answer (score 1):

Then you'll have to enable kernel crash dumps. As the Mint is based on the Ubuntu, this howto should be usable for you too:

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/kernel-crash-dump.html

Then next time something like that happens, core dump should be created and you can analyse it.

But according to your description, I'd bet on some faulty memory module (maybe reinsert could be sufficient). Run memtest86 over the night.

Comment: When you say "analyze it", do you mean in the same sense we analyze an application crashes? Also, where will this core dump be created?

Comment: Yes, in /var/crash